# Input from EditText only taking in hints instead of text inputted

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a basic patient details activity that takes patient details and saves them to a text file. At the moment it works fine only that the input it is receiving from the edit textfields are the hints from edit text and not the actual info I am trying to input. My code to me seems perfect and I cannot see where I am going wrong:

```
public class PatientDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

public EditText IDNum, name, DOB, weight, height;
public String   ID, dob, wght, hght, nme;
public Button   b;
public TextView t;
private FileUtility myFile = new FileUtility();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_patient_details);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    IDNum = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.IDnum));
    DOB = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.DOB));
    weight = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Weight));
    height = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Height));
    name = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name));
    b = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.submit));

    t = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result));

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ID = IDNum.getText().toString();
            dob = DOB.getText().toString();
            wght = weight.getText().toString();
            hght = height.getText().toString();
            nme = name.getText().toString();

            myFile.createFile(getApplicationContext(), "test");
            myFile.writeLine(ID);
            myFile.writeLine(dob);
            myFile.writeLine(wght);
            myFile.writeLine(hght);
            myFile.writeLine(nme);
            t.setText(myFile.readAll());
        }

    });


    }

}
```

xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_patient_details"
tools:context="com.example.user.filetest.PatientDetails">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/IDnum"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Patient ID number" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/Height"
    android:layout_below="@+id/IDnum"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Height"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/Weight"
    android:hint="Weight"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Height"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/DOB"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Weight"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="DOB" />

<Button
    android:hint="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/DOB"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_below="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/submit"
    android:textSize="7dp" />
```

/////file utility/////////

```
public class FileUtility {

private File root;
private File file;

public FileUtility() {
    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
}

public void createFile(Context context, String fileName) {
    try {
        if (root.canWrite()) {
            file = new File(root, "//" + fileName);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "//" + fileName); // File(root, "//" + fileName);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "fail to create a new file");
    }

}


public String readAll() {
    StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader in;
        FileReader datawriter = new FileReader(file);
        in = new BufferedReader(datawriter);
        if (file.exists()) {
            String str = null;
            while((str=in.readLine())!=null)
            {
                returnString.append(str + "\n");
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "fail to write file");
    }
    return returnString.toString();
}

public void writeLine(String message) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter out;
        FileWriter datawriter = new FileWriter(file,true);
        out = new BufferedWriter(datawriter);
        if (file.exists()) {
            out.write(message + "\n");
            out.flush();
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "fail to write file");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you provide the full java and XML code?

Comment: How did you know that you get the text hints? Only from the textview? Then you should show us your method myFile.readAll(), I guess there is something wrong...

Comment: please provide full code

Comment: @Kaushal28 all code provided now

Comment: Where is `toolbar` id in XML?

Comment: Fixed by changing name of text file

Comment: So you were reading the wrong textfile?

Comment: Your issue is that you do not clear the contents of the file and not that you were using a wrong text file name. In a subsequent run of your application you will get values from your previous run, and unless this is what you want, you will have to clear the contents of your file each time you open it. Confirm this and I'll write a potential solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try search your code one more time. You cannot get hint text from getText() method... unless you have hard pre-filled that hint as a text in EditText element.

Answer (score -1):

Try this maybe:

```js
 IDNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IDnum);
```

Comment: I agree. It's a rather peculiar issue the OP has raised.